# "removing" parts of an image with matlab

Tags: image-processing, matlab

for an assignment, I'm supposed to work with matlab, with the image below.
The task is to convert this image to a grayscale version (which wasn't a problem) and then to alter the image with *imadjust* so that only the writing and the arrows (not the shells) are visible. Since both the shells and arrows are yellow, I'm wondering how that would work. I tried different low high respectively in- and outputs for imadjust and also different gamma values, but none of that works.

Thanks!

[image]

edit: here's the grayscale version I got. I used *imadjust (img,[0.9;1],[],0.15)*

[image: grayscale version]

Comment: Can you show the grayscale image you get?

Comment: Also Imadjust is a contrast enhancement function, it's not suppose to vanish objects in the image

Comment: 1. use cropped image of a shell as template 2. using template matching find all position (x,y) of shells in picture 3. make a blue (background) mask with size of your template image 4. substitute the mask pixels with corresponding pixels of the detected shell